# Python extract data from files on ftp server and append to pandas data frame in offline and real time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, ftp

I am trying to write a script which can extract data from files already present on an ftp server(if any) and keep monitoring the ftp directory for any new incoming files extract data from new appearing files as well and append to a data frame. In more detail :

- Login in to FTP server in a given folder
- If any files are present in the folder Extract data from each file using some function and append to pandas data frame
- Continue watching the directory for any new files which appears , extract data from newly appeared file and append to pandas data frame
- Wait for new files to appear if the wait exceeds a time limit exit

What I have written so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from ftplib import FTP
from time import sleep
import time

# Here I define my empty data frame to which I will append my extracted data
cols = [  'Channel' , 'Voltage' , 'Amplitude',  'Time_(ms)', 'Bubble_period_(ms)']
all_results =  pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)

# Here I define my empty list which will be used to append the 
data = []


#Function to monitor FTP and extract data
def extract_ftp_results(ftp_folder_path):
    global all_results

    ftp = FTP()
    ftp.connect('10.199.44.240', 21)
    ftp.login('display')

  
    ftp.cwd(str(ftp_folder_path))
    print("Connection Established {}".format(ftp.getwelcome()))
    

    #Local directory where I copy each file for extracting attributes/data
    direct = 'C:\\Users\\QC\\Desktop\\ftp_local\\'

    #Create a list with one element to compare with the contents of ftp directory
    # it will to be used in running for loop later in the function  
    old_files = ['1']

    #Start a while loop to monitor the ftp directory 
    while True:                       #Start a while loop to monitor FTP directory 
        new_files = ftp.nlst()        #List the filenames of FTP directory and store in variable 
        if len(old_files) != 0 and new_files != old_files:    # Check if filenames match with old_files
            changes = [i for i in new_files if i not in old_files] # store the contents which don't match
        
            for x in changes: #for each filename that was not in the old_files
                filename = str(direct + x) # Define a filename where it will be written 
                localfile = open(filename, 'wb') #Open that filename in write mode
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR'+' ' + x , localfile.write, 1024) #Fetch from FTP and write
                localfile.close() # Close file
                print("updating data ***************************************************")
                print("found new file---> {}".format(str(filename).split('\\')[-1]))
                print("")
                print("Calculating  Attributes")
                print("*****************************************************************")
                sensor_arr , nfh_arr, gcs, mask, chan  = extract_data(filename) #extract data in np.array
                i=0
                num_cluster = 18
                sequence = gcs[11:19]
                shot = gcs[25:29]
                while i < num_cluster:  #loop through the numpy array extracted from file
                    poa, pot, bp = bubble_attributes(apply_filter(nfh_arr[15:500, i]))#extract attributes
                    values = [shot, chan, poa, pot, bp]
                    zipped = zip(cols, values) # zip attributes with column name 
                    a_dictionary = dict(zipped) # convert to dictionary 
                    data.append(a_dictionary) # Append dictionary to data list 
                    chan = chan +1
                    i += 1 
               os.remove(filename) # remove file from local machine 
               all_results = all_results.append(data, True) # append list of dictionaries to dataframe
            old_files = new_files
            a = time.perf_counter() #start time counter
            
            
            if time.perf_counter() > a + 100:
               print("Done Waiting") # break if wait for new file appearing exceeds
               break
```

The problem is that I am getting a data frame with repeating values from the file getting appended to the data frame again and again like for each element of new_file list the loop runs from starting every time.
Can someone please help

Comment: Do the files in `changes` contain data that is also in `old_files` file?

Comment: I actually defined old_files as a hack to monitor the directory for any new files which appear in it , contents of the ftp directory  will be stored again and again in the new_files(Python list) variable and they will be subsequently checked if they match the contents of the old_files (Python list) if they don't match then the element which did not match will move down to the for loop. Once the for loop finishes the new_files will be made equal to old_files, I forgot to add that in code , editing now

Comment: `values = [shot, chan, poa, pot, bp]` - each dictionary contains multiple *data points*? Is there a way to distinguish a unique data point - how can you tell if there is a duplicate? Will each unique data point have a unique `(shot,chan)` value? You need to filter before *saving* or afterwards but you need to know how to determine unique points.

Comment: yes each (shot,chan) value is unique

Comment: I tried using `all_results = all_results.drop_duplicates()`
But it is not worth it as the values in loop always start from the first value or element of changes (Python list) variable , which make the loop take very long time

Comment: `[shot, chan, poa, pot, bp]` are each of those arrays/lists/sequences - multiple datapoints? What type specifically? I'm thinking you want to keep a list/set/array of `shot,chan)` that has already *been seen* and filter new data on that before keeping it. The data type(s) will change how that might be done.

Comment: each of them are individual data points , e.g. , shot =1001(int), chan=1 to 18(int) , poa = float, pot =float, bp=float

Comment: Each files that I am trying to extract data from has a unique sp number and contains  electrical signals in form of numpy arrays from 18 different channels   , with the extract data function I am extracting these 18 numpy , in the second while loop I am extracting the peak voltage , time of peak voltage and another attribute bp from each of these signals with their channel numbers

Answer (score 0):

> each (shot,chan) value is unique

Keep a set of `(shot,chan)` tuples that have already been seen; check each new point against that set before *keeping* the data point.

```
...
seen = set()

#Function to monitor FTP and extract data
def extract_ftp_results(ftp_folder_path):
    ...

    #Start a while loop to monitor the ftp directory 
    while True:                       #Start a while loop to monitor FTP directory 
       ...

            for x in changes: #for each filename that was not in the old_files
                ...
                while i < num_cluster:  #loop through the numpy array extracted from file
                    poa, pot, bp = bubble_attributes(apply_filter(nfh_arr[15:500, i]))#extract attributes
                    values = [shot, chan, poa, pot, bp]
                    if (shot,chan) in seen:
                        continue
                    seen.add((shot,chan))
                    zipped = zip(cols, values) # zip attributes with column name 
                    a_dictionary = dict(zipped) # convert to dictionary 
                    data.append(a_dictionary) # Append dictionary to data list 
                    chan = chan +1
                    i += 1 
               ...
```

---

Sets are good for membership testing, you can improve the way you *find* new files using a set.

```
...
    old_files = set()

    #Start a while loop to monitor the ftp directory 
    while True:                       #Start a while loop to monitor FTP directory 
        new_files = set(ftp.nlst())        #List the filenames of FTP directory and store in variable 
        changes = new_files - old_files    # get new filenames
        if not changes:
            continue
        old_files.update(changes)
        for x in changes: #for each filename that was not in the old_files:
            ...
            os.remove(filename) # remove file from local machine 
            all_results = all_results.append(data, True) # append list of dictionaries to dataframe
        #old_files = new_files
        a = time.perf_counter() #start time counter
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks @wwii I'll implement this and check , also thanks for the improvement suggestion

Comment: Where do I define my for loop here , for x in changes , where I capture each element of changes, after continue put else ? as after True or False boolean is checked for the set being empty or not?

Comment: @abhishake - see edit - that whole for loop can be *dedented* one level. `if not changes: continue` will go back to the top of the while loop if there aren't any new files. [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement).   And you will need to delete `old_files = new_files` near the bottom of the `while True` loop.

Comment: I am still having some issue as the rows in dataset are being repeatedly copied , let me create a reproducible example, i''l the example in my code , you can use you phone as ftp server and client for this experiment , i'll create some dummy numpy files which mimic the files i have